# Compile error when trying to use increment operator

Tags: rust

During work on a side project I've tried to use an increment operator, as following:

```
fn main() {
    let mut my_var = 5;
    my_var++;
}
```

and received the following error:

```
error: expected expression, found `+`
 --> src\main.rs:3:12
  |
3 |     my_var++;
  |            ^
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: This question is literally in the FAQ on the Rust website :/.

Comment: @kirelagin Yep, but given the above compile error, how I supposed to know that? It took me a while to find, and I believe there will be others who will search for similar error message.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Increment (++) and decrement (--) operators are **not supported** in Rust.

From [Rust's FAQ](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/complement-design-faq.html#why-no---x-or-x++?):

> **Why doesn't Rust have increment and decrement operators?**
>   Preincrement and postincrement (and the decrement equivalents), while
>   convenient, are also fairly complex. They require knowledge of
>   evaluation order, and often lead to subtle bugs and undefined behavior
>   in C and C++. `x = x + 1` or `x += 1` is only slightly longer, but
>   unambiguous.

Comment: Could it be a new question **why** there are no increment and decrement operators in Rust?